# How to get component attached resources programmatically?

Tags: jsf, resources, jsf-2.2, facelets

JSF: how to get component attached resources programmatically? For example,

```
<h:componentA>

<h:outputStylesheet library="foo" name="bar.css" target="head"/>

</h:componentA>
```

How to get resources attached to the componentA inside the component renderer?

```
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent componentA)  {
   ...
}
```

It seems that facelet handler moves all such resources to UIViewRoot.

But from UIViewRoot.getComponentResources(context, "head"), we can not tell which
resources attaches which components.

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: For example, a custom <h:head> renderer needs to render resources attached to <h:head>, but not other component resources.

Comment: UIComponent should have a method like getAttachedResources(). It is better not to lose information present in facelet pages.